# RewriteCond doesn't match properly on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to point ipv4 adress (51.255.51.165) and the VPS url server (vps227127.ovh.net) to just one domain.

I have tried with this rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vps227127.ovh.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^51\.255\.51\.165
RewriteRule (.*) http://krioma.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second condition works fine, it redirects 301 to http://krioma.com, but it seems ignoring the first condition. Maybe I'm wrong something.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vps227127.ovh.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^51\.255\.51\.165
RewriteRule (.*) http://krioma.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Because without `OR` it's implicit `AND`

Answer (score 2):

Typically if you don't specifically tell Apache you want either one, it will use the default `AND` and both conditions would have to be true for it to work. You need to use the special [`OR`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) flag so that if either one is met, then proceed to the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vps227127.ovh.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^51\.255\.51\.165
RewriteRule (.*) http://krioma.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```